# print double type data and decimal represention

Tags: c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
uint64_t f: 23;
uint64_t e: 8;
uint64_t s: 8;
} float_struct_t;

typedef union {
float fp;
uint32_t bits;
float_struct_t bitss; 
} float_bits_t;


void printBitsFloat(float_bits_t *);


int main() {
float values[17];// =  {0.0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
float_bits_t x1;





x1.bitss.s = 0; 
x1.bitss.e = -2+127; 
x1.bitss.f = 0x4ccccd; //O prefixo 0x indica que o valor é representado em hexadecimal




int valores_e[] = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, -2, -3, -6, 1, 4, 5, 7};  
int valores_f[] = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4ccccd, 0x4ccccd, 0x23d70a, 0x0, 0x200000, 
0x200000, 0x480000}; 

for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(values)/sizeof(float); ++i) {
  x1.bitss.s = values[i];
  printf("%.1e: ", x1.fp);
  printBitsFloat(&x1);
  printf(" Sign = %d Exp(decimal) = %3d Fraction = 0x%x=%f", x1.bitss.s, x1.bitss.e-127, x1.bitss.f);
  putchar('\n');
}
 
}

/* Imprime o valor de cada bit, da esquerda para direita, desde o  
 bit firstBit (0 a 63) até ao bit lastBit (0 a 63 e não superior a firstBit)
*/
void printBits64(uint64_t v, int firstBit, int lastBit) {
uint64_t mask = 1; 

if(firstBit < lastBit)
  abort();

if(firstBit>0)
  mask = mask << firstBit;

if(mask & v)
  putchar('1');
else
  putchar('0');

if(firstBit == lastBit)
  return;
else {
  printBits64(v, --firstBit, lastBit);
}
}


void printBitsFloat(float_bits_t *x){
printBits64(x->bits, 31, 31); putchar(' ');
printBits64(x->bits, 30, 23); putchar(' ');
printBits64(x->bits, 22, 0);
}
```

Hello everyone, I'm trying to make a problem where a certain code is given and ask me to add to the code some additional way to print the decimal representation of the numbers. I used %f but all the results are giving me 0.0000. What could I do wrong? Later I am also asked to add the code that allows me to store and print the double type data, how can I do that? Thank you

Comment: Turn on warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`. Your code fails to include `<stdio.h>`. When that is fixed and you enable warnings, the compiler will warn you that the `printf` line has more `%` conversions than arguments for them. Fix that. The sign field of a floating-point encoding is 1 bit, not 8. Fix that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `-Wall -Wextra` for GCC, at minimum. `-Wall` isn't "all", not by a long shot -- it is *documented* as "all *the easily fixed ones*".

Comment: `printf(" Sign = %d Exp(decimal) = %3d Fraction = 0x%x=%f", x1.bitss.s, x1.bitss.e-127, x1.bitss.f);` count the number of parameters and the number of passed arguments.

Comment: Note that you may *read* out of a `union` only that type *which you last wrote*. Writing one type (`x1.bitss`) and reading another (`x1.fp`) is often showcased in "hacky" code, but it *is* undefined behavior.

Comment: @DevSolar is UB in C++, in C it is legal.

Comment: @DevSolar: C 6.5.2.3 3 specifies that using a member designator provides the value of the named member, and that paragraph does not restrict the designator to be that of the last member into which a value was stored, and a footnote makes it clear: “If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called "type punning")…”

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Bits not contained in the object representation of the type written take unspecified values on writing, and will be interpreted in the object representation of the type read. The only (!) type *guaranteeing* to allow conversion of bit representation to and from other types is `unsigned char[]`. I agree that type-punning *works* on many platforms, but that is up to the platform. There is *no guarantee whatsoever* that bitfield, `float`, and `uint32_t` are compatible with each other. Heck, there is not even a guarantee that `uint32_t` *exists* on every platform. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: bit-fields, `float`, and `uint32_t` are guaranteed not to be compatible, by the rules in the C standard about compatibility. That is irrelevant; compatible is not the criterion for whether or not a union member may be read. Nor is aliasing relevant; the aliasing rules in 6.5 7 are about accessing an object through an lvalue expression of type other than its effective type. But the type of the lvalue of a union member expression is the effective type of the union member (assuming the left operand of the `.` is the union), so the aliasing rules are satisfied.

Comment: @DevSolar: The relevant text of the C standard is as I cited, a paragraph specifying what the union member operator does, not restricting it to the last member written, and a note clearly stating union members may be used to reinterpret bytes. This is not up to the platform; C implementations that conform to the C standard must reinterpret the bytes when a union member other than the last one stored is read.